# How to display https image in react native?

Tags: react-native

Image tag of react-native is working but image is not showing in the android emulator. Only the card is coming. Screenshot of source code is attached below.[image: source code]

Comment: What are you seeing instead to the image? Do you see any errors? How does it look like in iOS?

Comment: Only card is coming. You can see the screenshot on ```http://develop.fifokart.in/Screen%20Shot%202019-09-12%20at%2011.42.29%20AM.png```

Comment: Did you try to put the image in a separate view, not inside a card?

Comment: @MohammedAlawneh Yes i have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will help you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet , Image} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
  let Image_Http_URL ={ uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/react_thumb_install.png'};

 return (
 <View style={{elevation:10, justifyContent: 'center', flex:1, margin:10}}>
 <Image source={Image_Http_URL} style = {{height: 200, resizeMode : 'stretch', padding:5 }} />
 </View>
 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check 2 things May be it solve issue**

1 : Internet permission is added in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2 : Is internet working on simulator? Try to check in browser of simulator.